# How to name a gem which depends on another's gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, rspec

I want to create a gem containing custom rspec matchers. They're for testing web services, so the two word parts are RSpec and Webservice. Now, should the gem name be;

- `rspec-webservice`
- `rspec-matchers-webservice`
- `rspec_webservice`

... or something else?

**The [naming guidelines](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/) don't seem to address this case:**

`rspec-webservice` seems correct because I am "adding functionality to another gem". But this will correspond to the gem residing in RSpec::Webservice, and I'm not the maintainer of RSpec, and so a naming conflict can arise.

`rspec-matchers-webservice` is a possibility because that seems to be how the RSpec library itself [is organized](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers).

`rspec_webservice` is a safe option, because it will simply be in its own root namespace (RSpecWebservice), and conflicts will be ruled out because the rubygems system will ensure that this name cannot be used for another gem.

All these concerns are totally separate from the question of whether such an RSpec extension will even **run** in the various namespaces.

EDIT: One piece of advice I've been given is to not go with any of these and instead come up with a non-descriptive name. Analogous to *passenger* for the web server. E.g. `rspec-dogweather`.

Comment: There's no particular convention. If you're creating the gem for distribution, just make sure the name isn't taken on [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org).

Comment: I'd say there's definitely a convention: http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard guideline in this case. Here's a few approaches:

If your gem provides extra features to an existing library, it's quite common to use the pattern `original-feature`. Notable examples:

- rspec-rails
- net-ssh
- guard-rspec

Note that this approach is also used to split a product into component

- rspec-matchers
- rspec-core

In this case, it's common to have the feature embedded into the main library namespace. As you mentioned, there is a potential risk for name clashing.

`rspec-matchers-webservice` it's a choice, but I don't see the `rspec-matchers` "component". Not that will prevent you from using such choice. I've seen other libraries using a different order such as [`rspec-html-matchers`](http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-html-matchers), but I think `rspec-matchers-foo` is better.

`rspec_webservice` is safer, but it's not very common.

Another possibility is a completely new name, but this may not be a wise choice, especially if your library has a very small nike and it's likely to be found from people searching on a search engine or on RubyGems website. In your case, I would stick with a name close to the product you extend.

In conclusion, my suggestion is to have a look at the existing [rspec extensions](http://rubygems.org/search?query=rspec) to have an idea about possible common patterns and take a decision. `rspec-matchers-webservice` seems to me the best choice.

You can also consider to write to the RSpec maintainers and ask them an advice.

Comment: I got this reply from Myron Marston: If your library is meant to only provide matchers (and not other functionality), I'd recommend `rspec-webservice_matchers` (with the `RSpec::WebserviceMatchers` namespace).  This is simliar to the recently extacted https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers gem.

Answer (score 0):

See [Name your gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/) on the RubyGems Guide.

Basically:

1. Use underscores for multiple words
2. Use dashes for extensions

You can mix underscores and dashes as needed.